# How can I get iCal to sync with iCloud while running Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, data-synchronization, icloud, ical, calendar

I have been looking for a few weeks for a workaround to get iCal on Snow leopard to sync with iOS 5 devices with iCloud.

Is there a work around that will allow syncing as I cannot upgrade to OSX Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a suitable work around that I have been testing for a couple of days.

While using iCal on a Mac running Snow Leopard, I needed to add an account to iCal. This account would point to iCloud and sync with it.

So, open Preferences and select accounts, enter the add account window by hitting +.

this takes you to:

[image]

You need to choose CalDav and enter your Apple ID email address (not your .me.com email address)

enter in your password and the server name which in most cases is `p06-caldav.icloud.com`

Once this has been added you will need to uncheck some of the calendars in the 'on my mac' menu.

Comment: if you are using a gmail address make sure you are using the CalDav server (it may try to reroute to gmail, if it does you can use your apple@me.com email address.